# help with huffman code

Tags: python

ok I have my huffman class which seem to be working fine. however when I am trying to make my binary tree I keep on getting an error message saying that ''the global name encoding is not defined'' when the name of my function is encoding. Can someone please tell me why? below is my code. Thank you

```
def get_encoding(self):
        # Huff is a previously defined function that generates the tree 
        node=self.Huff()
        dic={}
        if node.char:
            if not self:
                dic[node.char]='0'
            else:
                dic[node.char]=self
        else:
               encoding(self+'0',node.left)
               encoding(self+'1',node.right)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make a recursive call to get_encoding, but the signature differs since the definition doesn't take 2 parameters.  There may also be a problem with you trying to do `self+'0'` and `self+'1'`.

Comment: @ John. Thank you for your response. Anyway,I noticed that also and I made the corrections but for some unknown reasons it still gives the same stupid error message

Comment: @ Johnthat 'the global name get_encoding is not defined'

Comment: @ john I actually rewrote the whole thing. But I can not get it to call the get_encoding function into itself

Answer (score 0):

The name of your function is not `encoding`, it's `get_encoding`.

Comment: it was typo. even when I have the get_encoding it still gives me the same error message

Comment: @steff, this is one reason why cut-n-paste is a great way to ask questions. :)